# How to pass multiple parameters through form action?

Tags: jsp, servlet-3.0

. .
    in my jsp page im using onclick event for a button. the event name is saveRecord(<%=rs.getInt(id)%>);". Here i'm passing the parameter of id.

```
The method is
function saveRecord(id){
    var f=document.form;
    f.method="post";
    f.action='../MesDelivery?id='+id;
    f.submit();
}
Here i want to pass some more multiple parameters like name,address,etc
How to do? pls help me frndz...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function as below

```
function saveRecord(id,name,address){
    var f=document.form;
    f.method="post";
    f.action='../MesDelivery?id='+id+'&name='+name+'&address='+address;
    f.submit();
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much dear frnd vineeth sivan for ur gud response.

Comment: But one small doubt. How to call that parameter values in onclick method block?   saveRecord(<%=rs.getInt(id)%>);